# php, with xpath order data

Tags: php, xpath

how with XPath order xml file?

File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<cars>
    <car>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Ford</name>
    </car>
    <car>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Audi</name>
    </car>
    <car>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>VW</name>
    </car>
</cars>
```

Display(result):

```
2
Audi

1
Ford

3
VW
```

Comment: some sample code what should be ordered? What you want achieve by that? Do you want to store it right after? Do you just like to display it afterwards? Be a little bit more precise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sorting cannot be accomplished using XPath (1.0 or 2.0),** because a `sort()` function is a higher-order function (requires a comparator function as one of its arguments), and higher-order functions are not supported in XPath until version 3.0, which is still a working draft only.

**You need to use the programming language (XSLT, C#, ..., etc.) that is hosting XPath in order to produce the sorted result**.

Comment: +1 In XPath 2.0, sequences have the order of construcction, so in theory you could sort, besides that finding a good expression for this it would be a challenge...

Comment: @Dimitre: `for $pos in (0 to count($sequence)-1), $item in $sequence return if (count($sequence[. lt $item])=$pos) then $item else ()`

Comment: @Alejandro: Good, though you should use `le`, not `lt`. Also, this only works on item types that support `le`. Of course, this is O(N^2).

Comment: @Dimitre: Maybe someone cleaver could come up with a better expression... ;) Some linear calculated sequence of positions. Ah! The operator must be `lt` because otherwise the `$pos` comparison will break.

Comment: @Alejandro: It must be obvious that using `lt` will not sort correctly a sequence in which some items are equal.

Comment: @Dimitre: No. The logic is return **all** the items having none lesser (maximum), one lesser (second maximum), two lesser (third maximum), etc. There is no item in the sequence for wich all the items (self included) are lesser, that's why the iteration is over the sequence's count less one.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is basically a query language on XML resource like the SELECT SQL's statment is for DBMS.

You can't change an XML file. You have to get its content by querying it and save the results in an other XML file (or the same).

You can use XSL to do it simpler (XSL use XPath queries).

Comment: Hi, i don't wish change file. I just wish show data from A to Z. With XPath query.

Comment: In your case, /cars/car/(id|name)/text() but it is no meaning to extract data that way. Do you have more precision about the query you want?